# django-cumulus : syncstatic command not found

Tags: python, django, python-module

I installed cumulus with - `pip install django-cumulus` and all the necessary things to my app settings file. But when i do `django-admin.py syncstatic` I get `Unknown command: 'syncstatic'`. Can you please point me. what am I doing wrong.

Doc I followed - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cumulus

My env details :

```
Python 2.7.3
Django 1.4.2
django-cumulus 1.0.5
python-cloudfiles 1.7.10
```

**Edit:**

When I do it with `manage.py` from my project I get following error

```
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)   
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cumulus/management/commands/syncstatic.py", line 54, in handle
        self.sync_files()   
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cumulus/management/commands/syncstatic.py", line 60, in sync_files
        servicenet=self.USE_SERVICENET)   File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudfiles/__init__.py", line 98, in get_connection
        return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   
File "/home/jimit/python/environments/forkodecrm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudfiles/connection.py", line 84, in __init__
        raise TypeError("Incorrect or invalid arguments supplied") 
TypeError: Incorrect or invalid arguments supplied
```

I have included the following settings in my settings.py

```
# cumulus rackspace config 

CUMULUS = {
    'USERNAME': 'myusername',
    'CUMULUS_API_KEY': 'myapikey',
    'CUMULUS_CONTAINER': 'mycontainer',
    'STATIC_CONTAINER': 'mycontainer',
    'USE_SERVICENET': False, # whether to use rackspace's internal private network
    'CUMULUS_FILTER_LIST': [] # a list of files to exclude from sync } 

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage' 

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStaticStorage'
```

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but I'd guess you should be using `manage.py` inside your project instead of `django-admin.py` to run that command, so your app settings are taken into account.

Comment: @JonClements In doc it is `django-admin.py`, but I tried `manage.py` see question edit

Comment: A quick look at that source shows that gets raised when the authentication fails

Comment: @JonClements Yes, but I verified the accesskey and username its correct.

Comment: Well - shouldn't `CUMULUS_API_KEY` and `CUMULUS_CONTAINER` not contain the `CUMULUS_` prefix? That's not in the docs....

Comment: @JonClements It worked :)... Thanks a lot - It is their on this link -http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cumulus... add answer will accept it

Comment: Okay - done. You may wish to contact the maintainer and get them to update the doc re: `django-admin`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23368/discussion-between-jimy-and-jon-clements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise - you need to use the `manage.py` local to the project you installed so it can use the appropriate settings (not `django-admin.py` as stated in the docs).

The `TypeError` was raised if the authentication fields aren't set.

Your code here:

```
CUMULUS = {
...
    'CUMULUS_API_KEY': 'myapikey',
    'CUMULUS_CONTAINER': 'mycontainer',
...
}
```

Should instead be (note no `CUMULUS_` prefix):

```
CUMULUS = {
...
    'API_KEY': 'myapikey',
    'CONTAINER': 'mycontainer',
...
}
```